# Number.toLocaleString('nb') not returning norwegian format in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format a number to norwegian format by using `Number.toLocaleString()`

It gives the correct format in Chrome, but not in Microsoft Edge.

`(1000).toLocaleString('nb', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})`

`"1 000,00"` <-- expected

`"1,000.00"` <-- actual result

Is Edge missing the norwegian format or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: On wich version are you testing on? Since current edge is just branded chrome.

Comment: Hmm I am able to reproduce this. FF + Chrome result in `1 000,00` but Edge in `1.000,00`. Maybe there is a missing localization?

Comment: Testing on Microsoft Edge Version 92.0.902.78

Comment: This looks like a bug.. Perhaps send them feedback via `ALT + Shift + i` XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work now in Microsoft Edge Version 94.0.992.31 (Official build)